# 2 primary keys with 1 foreign key

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to write 2 queries to create 2 tables. Both have :

One query:

```
   create table table1
    (ID integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),    
    Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    Primary key(ID,Code));
```

second query:

```
 create table table2
    (ID integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),    
    Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    Primary key(ID,Code)
    CONSTRAINT fkey FOREIGN KEY (Code) REFERENCES table2(Code));
```

But I want to make the foreign key to be only on the code.
Is it possible, it didnt work when I tried.
Thank you

Comment: "the foreign key" - *what* foreign key? You've shown us no information about any kind of foreign key.

Comment: i wrote that i want to foreign key to be only the "code" field

Comment: Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Saying it "didn't work" is not exactly providing anybody with enough information so they can help you.

Comment: By rule, you can't create a foreign key constraint on one column of composite key. You have to take reference of all the columns included in primary key of master table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, I'm thinking this is waht you're after?

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (
      ID INTEGER NOT NULL
                 IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY ( ID) , --code makes no sense in the Primary Key when ID is
      UNIQUE ( code )
    );


CREATE TABLE table2
    (
      ID INTEGER NOT NULL
                 IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY ( ID, Code ) ,
      CONSTRAINT fkey FOREIGN KEY ( Code ) REFERENCES table1 ( Code )
    );
```

Code needs to be unique in the key table.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
ID integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),    
Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
Primary key(ID),
Unique (Code)
```

That is, `ID`, by itself, is sufficient to identify a row in this table (by definition) and `Code`, by itself, is sufficient to identity a row in this table

Comment: but i want the code to be foreign key. not just a key

Comment: If `Code` is going to be the *referenced* column in a foreign key constraint, then it need to be the *entire* primary key, or to exist as the *sole* column in a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what a foreign key is. Your primary key in both tables is the ID, if you want both to have code as foreign key you need a 3rd table containing all codes, using the code as a primary key.

Better would be to use a 3rd table with 2 fields, id and code and use this id as your foreign key in the other 2 tables.

You'll get something like this:

Table 1:
ID - 
code_id -
field1 -
...

Table 2:
ID -
code_id -
field1 -
...

Table 3:
ID -
code

Comment: I want a table to contain ID and code.The other table should contain rows with code only from the first table

Comment: But both should have ID that show the row number and have no connection to other tables

Comment: In that case you should put your code as primary key in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

You have two columns(ID,Code) in 1st table and make them as a primary key. In 2nd Table you also make a primary key which contain two columns(ID,Code).
Foreign key must have same number of columns as primary key in references table.

In your query you must have declare 2 columns in foreign key in 2nd table like.

```
    create table table1
    (ID integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),    
    Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    Primary key(ID,Code));

--second query:

 create table table2
    (ID integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),    
    Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    )
   ALTER TABLE table2
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_table2_idCode PRIMARY KEY(ID,Code);  
    ALTER TABLE table2 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fkey FOREIGN KEY (ID,Code) REFERENCES table1(ID,Code);
```

Now if you want fk only on codes then you must follow given query

```
 create table table1
    (ID integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),    
    Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    Primary key(Code));

--second query:

 create table table2
    (ID integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),    
    Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    )
   ALTER TABLE table2
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_table2_idCode PRIMARY KEY(Code);  
    ALTER TABLE table2 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fkey FOREIGN KEY (Code) REFERENCES table1(Code);
```